# How to change behavior of dynamic combobox

Tags: jquery, html, combobox

Jquery:

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = $(this).attr('id').replace("combo", "");
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 10;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue != '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('div.'+thisComboBoxIndex).append(newComboBox);
        }
    } 
});​
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="1">
    <select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
        <option></option>
        <option val="1">Opt1</option>
        <option val="2">Opt2</option>
        <option val="3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="2">
    <select id="combo2" class="combo" data-index="2">
        <option></option>
        <option val="1">Opt1</option>
        <option val="2">Opt2</option>
        <option val="3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

​
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/19/)

As you can see in the fiddle, if you select option 2 the next combobox options will be: option 1 and option 3.

What i want is:

If I select option 2 the next combobox options should be : option 3 (only).

This means that based on option selected, the next combobx (the dynamic one) should not contain the options lower then itself.

How can that be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
 newComboBox.find('option').each(function(){
     if(this.value < selectedValue) $(this).remove();
 });
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/39/)

Comment: I'm sorry for late answer. Im testing it now, its almost what I was looking for :) Just need a tweek. When you select one option the next combobox shouldn't be filled, should be empty

Comment: I see, I've did that too :) But now I've a a weird problem :s Imagine 100 options (1-100), when I select any option, eg: 50, all options below 50 disappear, except those between 1-10. Weird! It's like (1,2,3,4,...,10,51,52,53,...,100)

Comment: You have to check it like `parseInt(this.value,10) < parseInt(selectedValue,10)` which is best for comparing integer values... See it working here... http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/42/